# If (x1,x2,...xn) follow a dirichlet distribution with all alphas=1, then I think xi~U(0,1)/summation[U(0,1)]. If yes, how to prove it?

Tags: distributions, dirichlet-distribution

If (x1,x2,...xn) follow a dirichlet distribution with all alphas=1, then I think xi~U(0,1)/summation[U(0,1)]. If yes, how to prove it? Note that xi are all positive and summation(xi)=1

Comment: What do you mean by "summation[U(0,1)]? You mean the sum of n independent U(0,1) ?

Comment: Yes, I mean sum of 'n' independent U(0,1). If not for n=2, can the hypothesis be true for large 'n'? The dirichlet numbers generated for example for n=18 seemed to indicate so.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you mean $X_i \sim \frac{U_i}{U_1 + \cdots + U_n}$ where the $U_i$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$.

This is not true. Take $n = 2$. Then $X_1 \sim \text{Beta}\bigl(\alpha_1, (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) - \alpha_1\bigr)$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_distributions)), that is $X_1 \sim \text{Beta}(1,1) = \mathcal{U}(0,1)$. This is not the same distribution as $\frac{U_1}{U_1+U_2}$.

This is true with $U_i \sim \text{Gamma}(1,1)$. More generally, if the $Y_i \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha_i, 1)$ are independent, then $X_i \sim \frac{Y_i}{Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n}$, and more precisely this is "jointly true":
$$
(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \left(\frac{Y_1}{Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n}, \ldots, \frac{Y_n}{Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n}\right).
$$
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution), where a proof is given.